# How to interpret this line integral question?

Tags: integration

> Calculate $$\oint_\omega xy~dx+y^2dy$$
>   Then it says "$\omega:[y=x,y=6x-x^2$" (the "$y=x,y=..$" are actually actually in different lines, but I don't know how to do that in latex.

Is it correct if I understand $\omega$ as the region captured by the two curves?

I.e. the black part in this diagram (red curve is $6x-x^2$, blue is $x$):

[image]

If this is correct, how do I parametrize this region?

E:

Second question: I don't understand the first part of the integral: $xydx$, does it make sense to have a $g(y)dx$ in a non-indefinite integral?

Comment: Use the begin{cases}...end{cases} ambient to write the parametrization to $\omega$. Please double check it because it seems to me that it makes no sense as it stands (I read $y=x$ and $y=6x-x^2$, which would imply $x=6x-x^2$).

Comment: No.  $xydx + y^2dy$ is a $1$-form.  Thus $\omega$ should be a curve.  The way it's written is not especially comprehensible, but I'm guessing that they mean the boundary of the region in your plot.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I rechecked it and I copied it correctly, I thought the same, but I don't understand what this question asks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine. The parametrisation is given by 
$$\omega=\{\gamma (x)=(x,6x-x^2)\mid x\in[0,5]\}\cup\{\delta(x)=(x,x)\mid x\in[0,5]\}.$$

And thus$$\oint_\omega F(x,y)\cdot d\vec x=\int_0^5F(\delta(x))\delta'(x)dx-\int_0^5 F(\gamma(x))\gamma'(x)dx$$

where $d\vec x =(dx,dy)$ and $F(x,y)=(xy,y^2)$.

Comment: $\{\gamma (x)=(x,6x-x^2)\mid x\in[0,5]\}$ is not a closed curve.

Comment: Doesn't that parametrization only gets a part of the parabola (and not the $y=x$ part)?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it, thanks :-)

Comment: I see, so the only thing in the domain is the boundary of the region I painted, right? I added a minor question related in the main post. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, and be careful that when you follow the boundary, the inside of the domain has to be on your left. Otherwise, you will have a result with the opposite sign. And when you say $f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ you refer at $$\begin{pmatrix}f(x,y)\\g(x,y)\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}dx\\dy\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you can do that, my given definition of a line integral for vector fields is $\int_\omega \vec f \cdot \vec t ds=\int \vec f(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)dt$, where $\vec t$ is the tangent vector, where is that in your first equation? why do you take the dot product of $F$ with $\vec{dx}$ (just so you get what you need?)? Sorry for so many questions, but I'm kind of lost...

Comment: Actually it's equivalent since $\vec tds$ is in fact $d\vec x$.